# NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create undefined method `current_sign_in_at'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nomethoderror

I am getting the following error when I try to sign in in my rails app. I used devise for authentication. My error is
    NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create
    undefined method `current_sign_in_at'

My user model is

```
models/user.rb
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
attr_accessible :admin,:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :college_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid
def admin?

end
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
user.provider = auth.provider
user.uid = auth.uid
user.email = auth.info.email
user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
#user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
#user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
user.save!
end
end
end
```

My schema is

```
db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140126101946) do

create_table "levels", :force => true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "profile_name"
t.string   "college_name"
t.string   "email",                  :default => "",    :null => false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "",    :null => false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.datetime "created_at",                                :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",                                :null => false
t.string   "provider"
t.string   "uid"
t.boolean  "admin",                  :default => false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

The code in my devise_create_users.rb is

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
  t.string :profile_name
  t.string :college_name
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
```

My trackable was commented and I removed the comments and then ran rake db:migrate but nothing happened. Now I cannot remove trackable as I need it. What I need is that somehow I can keep my devise as it is and also add trackable to it in such a way that it gets added to the schema.rb as well.

Comment: Did you do a `rake db:rollback` and then re-run the migration with `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add new columns to existing tables, simply updating already run migration is not going to work as the schema is at a later version than your existing migration's version.  If you wish to modify the existing migration, you could run a `down` migration with:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140126101944 # use version of the user migration
```

Then modify the migration adding the new columns as you've already done, then run `up` migration using:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140126101944 # use version of the user migration
```

A better approach is to add a new migration with the change if your application is already in production.

To add the `trackable` columns to existing `users` table:

```
class AddTrackableColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Trackable
      t.add_column :sign_in_count, :integer, :default => 0
      t.add_column :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
      t.add_column :last_sign_in_at, :datetime
      t.add_column :current_sign_in_ip, :string
      t.add_column :last_sign_in_ip, :string
    end
  end
end
```

Then run `db:migrate`:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Just a note that the up command needs a `:` like the down command

Answer (score 3):

In your `models/user.rb`

Change

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, 
       :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
```

to

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
       :validatable, :omniauthable
```

**i.e. remove** `:trackable`